# Stop mask appending '0'

Tags: asp.net, .net

When using an input mask, the field will append a '0' if the input doesn't meet the length of the mask.

The mask is as follows:

```
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" 
     runat="server" 
     ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" 
     Mask="9-999999999999" 
     MaskType="Number" 
     TargetControlID="Sub_Ord_NumTextBox" 
     OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" 
     AutoComplete="true"/>
```

So a number like:

> 1-123456789123

(14 characters, matching the mask)

is fine, but one like

> 1-12345678912

(13 characters)

will cause the saved field to add a zero:

> 1-123456789120

How do I prevent this from occuring?

Comment: Err, I should really read the documentation more. Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with great help from [the documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)!

> AutoComplete - True to automatically fill in empty mask characters not specified by the user
>
> MaskType=Number - Empty mask characters will be filled with zeros
>
> MaskType=Time - Empty mask characters will be filled with the current time
>
> MaskType=Date - Empty mask characters will be filled with the current date
>
> MaskType=DateTime - Empty mask characters will be filled with the current date/time

Setting AutoComplete = false seems to have solved my issue.